# JBoss7 client-cert authentication: Ciper suite in SSL Session is SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL

Tags: java, security, ssl, jboss, jboss7.x

I am trying to set up client certificate authentication with JBoss (so far tested with **7.1.0 Final** and **7.1.1 Final**, **Java 6** and **Java7**).

1) I've generated certificate based on [this](https://github.com/restful-java-web-services-security/source-code/blob/master/chapter02/client-cert-authentication/steps%20to%20generate%20certificates)

2) I've copied keystore.server and server.truststore into **/standalone/configuration** folder.

3) In standalone.xml I've created security domain

```
<security-domain name="RequireCertificateDomain">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="CertificateRoles" flag="required">
              <module-option name="securityDomain" value="RequireCertificateDomain"/>
              <module-option name="verifier" value="org.jboss.security.auth.certs.AnyCertVerifier"/>
              <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/my-users.properties"/>
              <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/my-roles.properties"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
    <jsse keystore-password="changeit" keystore-url="file:C:/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/server.keystore" truststore-password="changeit" truststore-url="file:C:/jboss/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/configuration/server.truststore"/>
</security-domain>
```

and HTTPS connector:

```
<connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" secure="true">
     <ssl password="changeit" certificate-key-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/server.keystore" verify-client="want" ca-certificate-file="${jboss.server.config.dir}/server.truststore"/>
</connector>
```

4) I've imported certificate to **/lib/security/cacerts** (later I've been trying access my secured WS by Spring RestTemplate - also no luck)

5) I've imported certificate into Internet Options -> Content -> Certificates -> Trusted Root CA (I can see that cert is trusted)

6) I've created simple JavaEE Rest WS, web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Area secured</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected_resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/account/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description>User with any role</description>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
            <user-data-constraint>
                <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>


<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>RequireCertificateDomain</security-domain>  
</jboss-web>
```

7) When trying to access via browser (Chrome/Firefox/IE) I get **HTTP Status 401 - No client certificate chain in this request**. In server.log I can see the followings:

```
Handshake failed: java.io.IOException: SSL handshake failed. Ciper suite in SSL Session is SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
```

I've search the Internet and found out that it may be a [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-3915) but was supposed to be fixed in 7.1.0 Final release. Unfortunately I keep getting this error both on 7.1.0 and 7.1.1 versions.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I am running into the same issue.  I take it that the browser is not even prompting you to choose the cert?  Have you tried using curl to send the credentials and turned up `javax.net.debug=ssl,handshake` ? You can then see the client and server responses in your jboss logs.  Here is the curl command.

`curl --cert ./cert.pem --key ./key.pem https://jbosshost:port -k -v`

You will need to use openssl to convert your p12 to cert and key .pems